# Query documents based on distinct value in MongoDB?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoid, distinct

I'm trying to grab some documents from a MongoDB collection, but there are a lot of very similar entries. Suppose there are 4 documents having `{title: "Foo", author: "John"}`, but I only want to return one of those in the result set. As in, only 1 record any time there's a document with a given set of duplicate values. How do you do that? Kind of like an `SQL SELECT DISTINCT(author), title`

**UPDATE**

I should clarify: I'm interested in displaying a list of say 100 titles, but only show 1 instance of the title, no matter how many authors have something with that title.

Comment: To begin with, `SELECT DISTINCT(author), title` reflects a misunderstanding of DISTINCT. It modifies the SELECT, all of it, to return only distinct rows, it is not a function or something.

Anyways, there's [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) , there's [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) but you need to provide more details for us to answer this question, it's not clear what you are trying to query.

Comment: Ok. So here's what I'm trying to do. I have some records like this:
`title: My Great Work, author: John, price: 15`
`title: My Great Work, author: Carol, price: 15`
`title: Something Else, author: John, price: 28`
`title: Something Else, author: Carol, price: 28`
`title: Yet Another One, author: Tim, price: 10`

And the result should just throw out duplicates that have the same title. I don't however, want to delete them. Just show one entry per title. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [distinct](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) command available in mongo.